# Stuck on Euler 18. My for loops aren't going up the rows

Tags: python

My code should compare the values on the bottom row and then add the highest out of each pair to the corresponding number above/adjacent to it. It works for the first row but doesn't iterate to get to the top.
Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below:

```
numbers = [
    [75],
    [95, 64],
    [17, 47, 82],
    [18, 35, 87, 10],
    [20, 4, 82, 47, 65],
    [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34],
    [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67],
    [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92],
    [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33],
    [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29],
    [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14],
    [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57],
    [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48],
    [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],
    [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]

row = 14
col = 0
for j in range(14):
    for i in range(len(numbers[row-1])):
        if numbers[row][col] > numbers[row][col+1]:
            numbers[row-1][col] += numbers[row][col]
            col += 1

        elif numbers[row][col] == numbers[row][col+1]:
            numbers[row-1][col] += numbers[row][col]
            col += 1

        else:
            numbers[row - 1][col] += numbers[row][col+1]
            col += 1
    row -= 1
    col = 0
```

Comment: Could you please give the link to the question or explain with an example?

Comment: Consider using `>=` to combine the first two cases of the `if` statement. Also you can use the index of the inner `for` loop instead of introducing the `col` variable and incrementing it. Similar for `row` and `j`. The code furthermore seems to work.

Comment: The problem is "linked" in the title: https://projecteuler.net/problem=18

Comment: What do you mean pair?

Comment: @AnnZen pretty sure the following functionality is meant: `numbers[row-1][col] += max(numbers[row][col:col+2])` with variables as in the sample. In words: For each pair of successive entries in each row, add the bigger one to the element "inbetween-above" it. Start this at the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
def get_max_sum(triangle, row_index):
    if row_index == len(triangle):
        return max(triangle[row_index - 1])
    row = triangle[row_index]
    previous_row = triangle[row_index - 1]
    row[0] += previous_row[0]
    for i in range(1, len(previous_row)):
        row[i] += max(previous_row[i], previous_row[i - 1])
    row[-1] += previous_row[-1]
    triangle[row_index] = row
    return get_max_sum(triangle, row_index + 1)


max_sum = get_max_sum(numbers, 1)
print(f'Max sum = {max_sum}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on the same logic used by you.

```
tri = """
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
"""

tri = tri.split("\n")[1:-1]
tri = [list(map(int, ele.split())) for ele in tri]

for row in range(len(tri)-2, -1, -1):
    for ind, ele in enumerate(tri[row]):
        if tri[row+1][ind] > tri[row+1][ind+1]:
            tri[row][ind] += tri[row+1][ind]
        else:
            tri[row][ind] += tri[row+1][ind+1]
    tri.pop()

print("Max sum:", tri[0][0])
```